# Javascript If List Cotains?

Tags: javascript

Im unable to figure out how to check if my List Contains a element.

```
 for (x in chatBoxes) {
            chatboxtitle = chatBoxes[x];

            if (chatboxtitle==obj[ i ].from) {
            //alert(obj[ i ].from + " YES !");
            } else {
            //alert(obj[ i ].from + " NOPE !");
            }
            };
```

***Question***
How does it work ? 
Or how to code it like If chatboxes contains obj[ i ].from then yes else no 
Cause at this moment it only works when there is a element in the Chatboxes List... 
If there is nothing then happens nothing

Comment: Please use the search before you ask a new question. (also doesn't seem to have anything to do with Java).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `chatBoxes` is an object, you need to use the flag to findout whether the object contains the said value, then after the loop you need to do the action which is depending on the contains flag.

```
var contains = false;
for (x in chatBoxes) {
    if (chatBoxes[x] == obj[i].from) {
        contains = true;
        break;
    }
};

if (contains) {
    alert(obj[i].from + " YES !");
} else {
    alert(obj[i].from + " NOPE !");
}
```

But if `chatBoxes` is an array

```
if(chatBoxes.indexOf(obj[i].from) > -1){
    alert(obj[i].from + " YES !");
} else {
    alert(obj[i].from + " NOPE !");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `chatBoxes` is an array, use [**indexOf()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

```
if (chatBoxes.indexOf(obj[ i ].from) > -1)
```